# How to make an array of objects from object array in vueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an Object array which is following
[image]

But, I need to show

- email: Email muss eine .....
- phone: Telefonnummer ist ...

How can I do this in javascript? Actually I need to use this in VueJs.

Comment: What have you tried so far? May you share a [mcve] of that?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the screenshot you are receiving this from props so we can do this in the template:

```
<template>
  <div class="errors">
    {{  failureReasons.email ? failureReasons.email[0] }}
  </div>
</template>
```

If you would like to get all the errors into a single array (e.g. `['Email mus...', 'Telefon ...']`) you can do:

```
<template>
  <ul>
   <li v-for="error in Object.keys(failureReasons).map(key => failureReasons[key][0])"> {{ error}} </li>
  <ul>
</template>
```